# Condition check in SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a trigger to insert some values into `T2` based on what has been inserted into `T1`. This is used to audit how long a process is taken by monitoring the value of the `Status` and a date diff in a report between two different status values.

I am missing where to include the condition if the `i.IdNumber` and `i.status` exist in the `tblEX1StatusChangeLog` table that do not do anything.

Any help would be much appreciated, and thanks in advance.

My issue is if the related object is modified in anyway I see duplicate status values and IdNumber where they should only be unique status for each of the ID numbers. I know I can massage the data in the report to provide desired results even with the duplicates however I want to minimize the data going into the changelog table.

```
create trigger trgEx1StatusChange 
on tblEx1 
after update, insert    
as 
begin
    insert into tblEx1StatusChangeLog (IdNumber, UpdatedOn, Status, updatedby)
        select i.IdNumber, GETDATE(), i.Status, SUSER_NAME()
        from tblQuotes as t
        inner join inserted as i on t.IdNumber = i.IdNumber
end
```

I would like to see these results

```
IdNumber   UpdatedOn    Status    UpdatedBy
----------------------------------------------
100001     04102019     Open      domain/user
100001     04132019     Closed    domain/user
```

Not

```
IdNumber   UpdatedOn    Status    UpdatedBy
----------------------------------------------
100001     04102019     Open      domain/user
100001     04102019     Open      domain/user (if the object related to idNumber-100001 is edited but status is not changed)
100001     04132019     Closed    domain/user
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, this community is awesome, I have always cruised it for reference.  This is my first posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
create trigger trgEx1StatusChange on tblEx1 after update, insert    
as 
begin
    insert into tblEx1StatusChangeLog (IdNumber, UpdatedOn, Status, updatedby)
        select i.IdNumber, GETDATE(), i.Status, SUSER_NAME()
        from tblQuotes t join
             inserted i
             on t.IdNumber = i.IdNumber
        where not exists (select 1
                          from tblEX1StatusChangeLog cl2
                          where cl2.IdNumber = i.IdNumber and
                                cl2.Status = i.status
                         );
end ;
```